# Lua custom UDP Header

Tags: header, lua, udp

Is there a way to create a custom UDP header in Lua? I am using **Ubuntu 11.10**, **Lua 5.1**, and **Luasocket**. Am I missing a module for this to work or is it impossible?

What I was planning to do is to send a character in the length section of the UDP header from the client then decode it on the server. Is there a better way of doing this without sending data via normal data transfer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to modify packet headers is to use raw sockets and construct the packet yourself, including both the IP and UDP headers.

However, what you want to do, use the length field for data, will not work. Remember that all routers/switches/hubs between your client and server looks at the header to determine how long the packet is. If there isn't a valid length there they will fail sending your packet on.

Comment: Yes, I realized that it wouldn't work even if I pad the data with enough bits to cover the length, and even with padding, I have a limit as to how much I can send. I'm going to think for another way to "covertly" send data. Thanks.